# ffmpeg h.264 video plays in Safari but not in Chrome

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm using ffmpeg to encode a .MOV raw video into a compressed H.264 video for display on an html5 website. I'm using the below string to encode the video:

```
ffmpeg -y \
-i in.mov
-b 3500k -bt 4000k \
-acodec libfaac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 192k \
-vcodec libx264 -vpre ultrafast -vpre baseline \
out.mp4
```

The resulting video looks great and plays fine in Safari, but Chrome can't recognize it. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution on this one? it seems that chrome can definitely play a h264 taken out of a camera, but not one from ffmpeg... :(

Answer (score 0):

I think [Chrome has dropped support](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/google-chrome-to-drop-h264-support-roadblock-to-html5/2856) for h264 because Google wants to use only open codecs that don't have patents on them, like WebM.

Answer (score 0):

Google has announced that they are dropping support for H.264 in Chrome. However, that was more than a year ago and they never committed to a timeline.

Meanwhile, I was reproducing the same problem described in this post. I eventually figured out how to make it work. The original question didn't specify the video tag in use. I found that if you simply specify:

```
<video src="file.mp4"></video>
```

and the video starts with a black frame it will appear to not work (just a black box that does nothing). Either specify 'autoplay="true"' to begin playback automatically or 'controls="yes"' for playback controls to appear.